# Need to do a specific regexp on a string

Tags: regex

I need help on doing a regexp on a string:

Here an example of the string:

```
(
    (nissan NEAR leaf) OR 
    env200 OR 
    "e nv200" OR 
    (
        (leaf OR evalia) NEAR (
            nismo OR 
            eletrico OR 
            "veiculo eletrico" OR 
            carregar OR 
            autonomia OR 
            hibrido OR 
            "zero emission" OR 
            recarregavel OR 
            "plug in" OR 
            electrified
        )
    )
) NOT (
    flor OR 
    fruto OR 
    "arvore jovem" OR 
    frutos OR 
    flores OR 
    "arvores jovem" OR 
    vegetal OR 
    vegetais OR 
    corrida OR 
    "drag racing" OR 
    "prova de arranques" OR 
    "desporto automovel" OR 
    "desporto motorizado" OR 
    automobilismo OR 
    "a venda" OR 
    "vende se" OR 
    "usado nissan" OR 
    "carro usado" OR 
    negocios OR 
    negocios OR 
    oferta OR 
    ofertas OR 
    policia OR 
    vendas OR 
    concessionario OR 
    concessionarios OR 
    licenca OR 
    patrocinio OR 
    patrocinador OR 
    "contrato de aluguer" OR 
    leasing OR 
    locacao OR 
    arrendar OR 
    "em segunda mao" OR 
    cardeals
)
```

I wanna match with my regexp only word with letter+number without quotes(simple or double) and ignore the ones with quotes(simple or double).

For instance in this string, i should match this word: env200.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the words between parenthesis?

Comment: For instance, i should match this word: env200 in this string.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a single regex, but I can write you the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to use this regex to remove all parenthesis and the word between them.

```
['"][\w\s]+['"]
```

Then use the string produce and extract the words

```
\b([\w]+)\b
```

You didn't specify your programming language (you should because regex engine are different for each programming language).

In PHP, you would do it like this:

```
$myString = '((nissan NEAR leaf) OR nv200 OR "e nv200" OR ((leaf OR evalia) NEAR (nismo OR eletrico OR "veiculo eletrico" OR carregar OR autonomia OR hibrido OR "zero emission" OR recarregavel OR "plug in" OR electrified))) NOT (flor OR fruto OR "arvore jovem" OR frutos OR flores OR "arvores jovem" OR vegetal OR vegetais OR corrida OR "drag racing" OR "prova de arranques" OR "desporto automovel" OR "desporto motorizado" OR automobilismo OR "a venda" OR "vende se" OR "usado nissan" OR "carro usado" OR negocios OR negocios OR oferta OR ofertas OR policia OR vendas OR concessionario OR concessionarios OR licenca OR patrocinio OR patrocinador OR "contrato de aluguer" OR leasing OR locacao OR arrendar OR "em segunda mao" OR cardeals)';


$myString = preg_replace(
    "/['\"][\w\s]+['\"]/",
    "",
    $myString
);

$words = array();

if (preg_match_all(
    "/\b([\w]+)\b/",
    $myString,
    $words
)) {
    $total = count($words[0]);

    for ($index = 0; $index < $total; $index++) {

        var_dump($words[0][$index]);
    }
}
```

You can test it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/60a64961bdce706db0ee735c785e1830a514089f

Comment: Thanks a lot Johathan.

Comment: I just added the loop a new regex to check for a word which contain number+letter:  if (preg_match("/((?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/", $words[0][$index])) {
            $result = true;
        }